# Global Filtering on Odata Provider

Tags: objective-c, sql-server, ios, wcf, odata

Im connecting to a multi-tenant database through an odata service (my client is an iOS app, using the obj-c OData SDK). My question is, is there a way to apply a global filter to all data calls. Every data call should be filtered by TenantID=?, so instead of going to every single data call and adding TenantID=? to the filter string (My app is already developed for single database and am now refactoring it for multi-tenant), i was just hoping there is a way to catch it in say the OnBeforeSend event and manipulate the URL to add the filter. So therefore all data calls are filtered. Any ideas? Or any suggestions on approaching this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that approach.
Another approach, which may not be applicable in your situation, is to filter it on the Odata side using change and query interceptors.